# spring-boot-configuration-processor 1.3.3.RELEASE (or 1.3.0.RELEASE) gives compile error with Maven 3.0.4

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm using `spring-boot-configuration-processor` 1.3.3.RELEASE with Maven 3.0.4 and `maven-compiler-plugin:3.3` and it gives a compile error when using JDK 1.7. The compile error gives no details either and in fact if I even just have a single interface class to compile it still fails.

What is odd is if I use JDK 1.8 or `spring-boot-configuration-processor` 1.2.6.RELEASE the compilation works fine.

Here is the output of a compilation.

```
C:\git-repos\Alpha>mvn -e -X clean compile
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: c:\xxx\fc-maven
Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Temp\jdk1.7_64\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
...
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.xxx.xyz:Alpha:jar:5.0.0
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, compile]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ Alpha ---
...
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.5:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]          log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4
[DEBUG]   Included: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@37af78ce]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes, C:\com\xxx\xyz\XYZBatchCommon\2.0.0-SNAPSHOT\XYZBatchCommon-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, C:\com\xxx\xyz\XYZBatchEngine\1.0\XYZBatchEngine-1.0.jar, C:\com\xyz\am\cs\util\cs-mailing-util-jar\2.0.0.5\cs-mailing-util-jar-2.0.0.5.jar, C:\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, C:\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar, C:\commons-collections\commons-collections\4.1\commons-collections-4.1.jar, C:\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, C:\commons-discovery\commons-discovery\20040218.194635\commons-discovery-20040218.194635.jar, C:\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar, C:\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.3.1\commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar, C:\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, C:\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar, C:\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.0.4\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, C:\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar, C:\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.6\commons-pool-1.6.jar, C:\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, C:\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.8\aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-messaging\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\spring-oxm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-oxm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\mybatis\mybatis-spring\1.2.5\mybatis-spring-1.2.5.jar, C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, C:\com\ibm\jbatch\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi\1.0\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar, C:\javax\batch\javax.batch-api\1.0\javax.batch-api-1.0.jar, C:\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar, C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-integration\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-batch-integration-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-core\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.1.1.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.0\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar, C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.5\jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\json\json\20141113\json-20141113.jar, C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.5\log4j-api-2.5.jar, C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.5\log4j-core-2.5.jar, C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-1.2-api\2.5\log4j-1.2-api-2.5.jar, C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jcl\2.5\log4j-jcl-2.5.jar, C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.5\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar, C:\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.13\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, C:\com\lmax\disruptor\3.3.0\disruptor-3.3.0.jar, C:\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.4.3\HikariCP-2.4.3.jar, C:\javax\mail\mail\1.4.7\mail-1.4.7.jar, C:\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar, C:\org\mybatis\mybatis\3.3.0\mybatis-3.3.0.jar, C:\com\sybase\jconnect\jconn4\7.07-27082\jconn4-7.07-27082.jar, C:\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0.2206.100\sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar, C:\com\xxx\grt\twofish\1.0\twofish-1.0.jar, C:\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.8\xstream-1.4.8.jar, C:\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.4a\xmlpull-1.1.3.4a.jar, C:\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream-benchmark\1.4.7\xstream-benchmark-1.4.7.jar, C:\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, C:\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar, C:\jxl\jxl\2.6.12\jxl-2.6.12.jar, C:\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.2\hsqldb-2.3.2.jar, C:\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.51\jsch-0.1.51.jar, C:\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar, C:\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar]
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerVersion = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = true
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile {execution: default-compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.xxx.xyz:Alpha:5.0.0 @ C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = com.xxx.xyz:Alpha:jar:5.0.0
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2df90731
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java]
....
[DEBUG] Output directory: C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes
[DEBUG] Adding C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations to compile source roots:
  C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java
[DEBUG] New compile source roots:
  C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java
  C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java\com\xxx\equity\common\IConstant.java
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[DEBUG] Classpath:
....
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.8\aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-messaging\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\spring-oxm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-oxm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\mybatis\mybatis-spring\1.2.5\mybatis-spring-1.2.5.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-integration\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-batch-integration-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-core\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.1.1.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
....
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\json\json\20141113\json-20141113.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
....
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java
[DEBUG]  C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes -classpath C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes;C:\com\xxx\xyz\XYZBatchCommon\2.0.0-SNAPSHOT\XYZBatchCommon-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\com\xxx\xyz\XYZBatchEngine\1.0\XYZBatchEngine-1.0.jar;C:\com\xyz\am\cs\util\cs-mailing-util-jar\2.0.0.5\cs-mailing-util-jar-2.0.0.5.jar;C:\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\commons-collections\commons-collections\4.1\commons-collections-4.1.jar;C:\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\commons-discovery\commons-discovery\20040218.194635\commons-discovery-20040218.194635.jar;C:\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.3.1\commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar;C:\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.0.4\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.6\commons-pool-1.6.jar;C:\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.8\aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-messaging\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\spring-oxm\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-oxm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\mybatis\mybatis-spring\1.2.5\mybatis-spring-1.2.5.jar;C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\com\ibm\jbatch\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi\1.0\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar;C:\javax\batch\javax.batch-api\1.0\javax.batch-api-1.0.jar;C:\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar;C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-integration\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-batch-integration-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-core\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.1.1.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.0.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar;C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.0\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar;C:\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.5\jackson-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\json\json\20141113\json-20141113.jar;C:\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.5\log4j-api-2.5.jar;C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.5\log4j-core-2.5.jar;C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-1.2-api\2.5\log4j-1.2-api-2.5.jar;C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jcl\2.5\log4j-jcl-2.5.jar;C:\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.5\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar;C:\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.13\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar;C:\com\lmax\disruptor\3.3.0\disruptor-3.3.0.jar;C:\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.4.3\HikariCP-2.4.3.jar;C:\javax\mail\mail\1.4.7\mail-1.4.7.jar;C:\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\org\mybatis\mybatis\3.3.0\mybatis-3.3.0.jar;C:\com\sybase\jconnect\jconn4\7.07-27082\jconn4-7.07-27082.jar;C:\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0.2206.100\sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar;C:\com\xxx\grt\twofish\1.0\twofish-1.0.jar;C:\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.8\xstream-1.4.8.jar;C:\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.4a\xmlpull-1.1.3.4a.jar;C:\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream-benchmark\1.4.7\xstream-benchmark-1.4.7.jar;C:\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;C:\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;C:\jxl\jxl\2.6.12\jxl-2.6.12.jar;C:\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.2\hsqldb-2.3.2.jar;C:\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.51\jsch-0.1.51.jar;C:\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar; -sourcepath C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java;C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations; C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\src\main\java\com\xxx\equity\common\IConstant.java -s C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -deprecation -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\git-repos\xyz-batch-jobs-ServerUpgrade-REFACTORING\Alpha\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.478s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 10 18:08:44 EDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project Alpha: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project Alpha: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:915)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not but my Maven project is a child project.
Below is the section of the pom that imports spring boot:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <xyz.spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</xyz.spring.version>
        <xyz.spring.boot.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</xyz.spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${xyz.spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${xyz.spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${xyz.spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can you make sure it is because `spring-boot-configuration-processor`?

Comment: just so you know, Spring Boot requires maven 3.2+

Comment: What is this exclusion on the configuration processor? There is no need to do that. You can also add `<optional>true</optional>` as it's only required during compilation. And there is no reason to hardcode a version either, just use the same `${xyz.spring.boot.version}` placeholder. Having said that, I see no evidence that the annotation processor is the culprit. Are you saying it works if you remove it?

Comment: @GeminiKeith If I leave the pom exactly the same only changing the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` from 1.3.3.RELEASE to 1.2.6.RELEASE the compile works.

Comment: @BrianClozel Understood however I'm not attempting to use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (which is what I thought required Maven 3.2+).  Also I just upgraded to I've also upgraded to Apache Maven 3.3.9 and I see the exact same issue.

Comment: Congratulations, you might find the reason. Sorry I didn't remember anything about the update between those two major releases.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll The reason for the hardcoding of the version rather than just using the same `${xyz.spring.boot.version}` placeholder was so that I could prove that if I changed this specific jar to an older version that it would not fail during compilation.  The exclusion was a carry-over from prior to adding the

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll The reason for the hardcoding of the version rather than just using the same `${xyz.spring.boot.version}` placeholder was so that I could prove that this specific jar version was the cause of the compilation error.  
The `exclusion` was a carry-over prior to me specifically adding the `org.json.json` dependency.
Your feedback prompted me to try letting `spring-boot-configuration-processor` use the version of json it has as a transitive dependency (specifically `20140107` rather than `20141113`):
When I allowed it to pull in that specific version the issue went away.  Thanks.